# Issue With Path Expansion Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I am having a problem with Windows path expansion using a batch file where the variable contains a string from the Windows registry.  See script below.  I have tried multiple methods but I must be missing something simple.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f ServiceDll /s ^| grep.exe -ia "REG_EXPAND_SZ" ') do (
set registry_value2=%%b
call :regmerge
)
goto :endofscript

:regmerge
echo !registry_value2!
goto :eof

:endofscript
endlocal
```

Comment: Can you describe what is not working, what you expect and what your current output is?

Comment: since when is grep standard on a Windows OS?

Comment: Yes, I could use a native command like findstr.  Is that really the core of the issue though?

Comment: So, what I want to happen is when I encounter %systemroot%\<filename>, I want to echo back the actual file path like C:\Windows\<filename>.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
set registry_value2=%%b
```

with

```
call set "registry_value2=%%b"
```

and remove the call to regmerge. The `call` will force the parser to do a second pass and replace the environment variables references.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with the use of findstr and storing the intermediate result in a temp file.

```
@echo off
rem tempfile
set tf=regfind.tmp

rem reg query output pipe into findstr and redirect to temnpfile
reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v ServiceDll /s | findstr /C:SystemRoot > %tf% 

rem iterate over each line in temp file and call merge
for /F "tokens=3*" %%a in (%tf%) do call :merge %%a

rem delete tempfile
del /q %tf%

goto :eof

:merge
rem SystemRoot is exapanded now...
echo %1 

goto :eof
```